# How to get the input words from the Tkinter Text Box when type the words?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I created text editor using Tkinter text box. I need to get input words, When type it. Without call any functions. I can get input details using by some functions. This is my code,

```
from tkinter import Tk, scrolledtext, Menu, filedialog, END, messagebox, simpledialog, StringVar


root = Tk(className=" Text Editor")
textArea = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=100, height=80)

def newFile():
    if len(textArea.get('1.0', END+'-1c')) > 0:
        if messagebox.askyesno("Save ?", "Do you wish to save ?"):
            saveFile()
        else:
            textArea.delete('1.0', END)
    root.title("TEXT EDITOR")

def openFile():
    textArea.delete('1.0', END)
    file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root, mode='rb', title='Select a text file', filetypes=(("Text file", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    if file != None:
        contents = file.read()
        textArea.insert('1.0', contents)
        file.close()

def saveFile():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')
    if file != None:
        data = textArea.get('1.0', END+'-1c')
        file.write(data)
        file.close()

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
fileMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="New", command=newFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=saveFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Find")
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit")
helpMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help")
menu.add_cascade(label="About")

textArea.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you written so far. show us your code.

Comment: I added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, scrolledtext, Menu, filedialog, END, messagebox, simpledialog, StringVar

root = Tk(className=" Text Editor")
textArea = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=100, height=80)

# --- added extra code for getting key pressed starts here --- #
word = ''
text = ''
def key(event):
    # if you only need the character of the key pressed #
    print("You Pressed: ", event.char)

    # if you need the words after pressing ' '(space) key, or the total text #
    global word, text
    if event.char == ' ': 
        text = text + ' ' + word
        print("Current Word You Entered: ", word)
        print("Total Text is: ", text)
        word = ''
    else:
        word += event.char
# binding key function to key pressed #
textArea.bind("<Key>", key)

# --- added extra code for getting key pressed ends here --- #


def newFile():
    if len(textArea.get('1.0', END+'-1c')) > 0:
        if messagebox.askyesno("Save ?", "Do you wish to save ?"):
            saveFile()
        else:
            textArea.delete('1.0', END)
    root.title("TEXT EDITOR")


def openFile():
    textArea.delete('1.0', END)
    file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root, mode='rb', title='Select a text file', filetypes=(("Text file", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    if file != None:
        contents = file.read()
        textArea.insert('1.0', contents)
        file.close()


def saveFile():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')
    if file != None:
        data = textArea.get('1.0', END+'-1c')
        file.write(data)
        file.close()


menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
fileMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="New", command=newFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=saveFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Find")
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit")
helpMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help")
menu.add_cascade(label="About")

textArea.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Partho63 Thank you.